# Return ndarray from Python-extension to C

Tags: python, c, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray, cpython

I have a C-program from where I call a Python function. I want this Python function to return a ndarray which I then could use in my C code. I need a ndarray, as I want to the Python code to record a sound and send the array back to the C code using sounddevice.record(). At the moment I am using PyArrayObject* as the variable type with which I am receiving (pValue). But all I get at the output are Zero's. I already tried this program for receiving integers and this does work, so it is specifically with passing array's where the problem lies.

C-code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Python.h>
#include <numpy/ndarrayobject.h>

int main(){
      PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pFunc;
      PyArrayObject *pValue;
      Py_Initialize();
      import_array();

      pName = PyString_FromString("audioPipe");
      pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
      Py_DECREF(pName);

      if(pModule == NULL) printf("its null\n");
      if (pModule != NULL) {
          pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "recordSound");        

          if (pFunc && PyCallable_Check(pFunc)) {
            pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, NULL);
            for(int r = 0; r < 10; r++){printf("%f\n", pValue[r]);}
            if (pValue == NULL) {
              Py_DECREF(pFunc);
              Py_DECREF(pModule);
              PyErr_Print();
              fprintf(stderr,"Call failed\n");
              return 1;
            }
          }
          else {
              if (PyErr_Occurred())
                  PyErr_Print();
              fprintf(stderr, "Cannot find function \n");
          }
          Py_XDECREF(pFunc);
          Py_DECREF(pModule);
        }
        else {
            PyErr_Print();
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load \\n");
            return 1;
        }
        Py_Finalize();
        return 0;
}
```

Python Code (in file audioPipe.py)

```
import sounddevice as sd
fs = 44100
channels = 2

def recordSound():
    recArray = np.arange(20)
    print recArray
    print type(recArray)
    return recArray
```

Output

```
PYTHONPATH=. ./audioPassing
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
```

Comment: You have better chance for a good answer if you provide a [mcve], because right now others need to fill the gaps in your code.

Comment: I am sorry, it is my first question. Better like this? or what do you otherwise mean with a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: To access the data-buffer of the numpy array you need to use PyArray_BYTES & friends https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html#c.PyArray_BYTES. `pValue` is a pointer to the object and not to the data-pointer.

Comment: I can't seem to find a working implementation of PyArray_Bytes. I think i have a pointer to the data of the array like this. But how do i acces this data? 

const double* temp = (const double*)(PyArray_BYTES(pValue));                

I tried using PyArray_GetPtr, but that did not seem to work. Another implementation i saw was using the strides

npy_intp stride = PyArray_STRIDES(temp);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++, temp+=stride)
        {
          printf("%f\n", *temp);
        }

But then i think i accessed wrong memory as i got really big nonsense numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to use the array. I converted it to a npy_float** type. (2 dimensional, necessary for my application) using the PyArray_AsCarray() function.
From then on you can use it. The bigger problem was mainly with my printstatement. I used the wrong format which caused it to be read wrong. Another important note is, to use the PyArray_AsCArray function you should use PyArray_Descr* instead of a typenum. Otherwise you get a segmentation fault.

```
PyArray_Descr *descr;
descr = PyArray_DescrFromType(PyArray_TYPE(pValue));

if (PyArray_AsCArray(&pValue, (void*)&array, PyArray_DIMS(pValue), PyArray_NDIM(pValue), descr) < 0)  {
   PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "error converting to c array");
   return NULL;
}
```

Important is, if you want to print it out you need to use as format.

```
printf("datapoint: %"NPY_FLOAT_FMT"\n", array[][]);
```